# Vertical slider, in which the filled bar change colour depending on how large the selected value gets

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, slider

I've already looked at,

[telerik slider](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/Slider?theme=vista)

[ajaxlibrary slider](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/slider/slider.aspx)

[jQuery slider](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/jQueryCodeSamplesMVC/Slider/SimpleSlider)

[jqueryui slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical) (presently implemented)

which so far I prefer the 1st and 4th options but I ideally need a slider which depending on how large a value will change it's filled bar colour, so say green = 0-3, yellow = 4-7 red = 8-10.

Anybody know of any other sliders which can do this or instead on how to change any of these sliders to do it.

I also need to record the slider value in case any suggested sliders don't do that and am possibly going to place the slider over an image in case any suggested sliders might have that built in which would greatly favor that slider as my choice.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Guess this indicates either there isn't a package slider out there or that anybody who knows of one hasn't read this yet.  I'll leave this up till friday and if by then I haven't got an answer then it will 1 be to late to most likely implement a different slider and 2 be obvious there isn't one and I'll delete this topic. (that is ofc if I remember to do so on friday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could be a good place to start. All i've done is change the background colour of the slider based on the value of the slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/HUXpg/1/

```
$(function() {

    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            var g = parseInt(ui.value <= 50 ? 255 : 255 - ((ui.value-50)*(255/50)));
            var r = parseInt(ui.value >= 50 ? 255 : 255 - ((50-ui.value)*(255/50)));
            $(".ui-widget-header").css("background-color", "rgb("+r+","+g+",0)");  
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="amount">Volume:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
</p>
```

CSS: (just to override the default settings)

```
.ui-widget-header {
     background-image: none;
     background-color: rgb(255, 200, 0);   
}
```

Comment: Since this is the only answer and I'm not sure when I'll get a chance to implement it I'll mark this as correct for now.