# trackbar in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, trackbar

I have a quite simple question is there a trackbar class available in ASP.NET MVC 5? I looked it up on google and the only trackbar extention + tutorial that I could find was DevExpress :(. I know that you can get the trackbar class in ASP.NET webforms but I am not sure if that same class is also available for ASP.NET MVC 5 solusions.

I am just looking for something simple to implement it's for school by the way. If you guys can give me some usefull documentation/tutorials or links how to accomplish this it would be amazing.

Comment: If by trackbar you mean sliders, you will find a *lot* of Javascript sliders, including jQuery UI's [slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there not an .NET class for this?

Comment: like in webforms, but I will look into the JavaScript sliders, do you have any links on some good tutorials/documentation?

Comment: Forget webforms. Forget server side controls. This is a client operation, so use the client side: implement it in Javascript.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC generates HTML and Javascript. The HTML helpers you use are exactly that - helpers that generate HTML and javascript. The entire philosophy of MVC is to separate the client-side UI from the server-side code.

Comment: As for tutorials - I *do* use jQuery slider in MVC projects, as well as Telerik's Kendo UI controls, jQRangeSlider and a lot of others.All of them have samples and tutorials

Comment: mmmmh interesting @PanagiotisKanavos I will look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 has already supported trackbar, you can run the snippet to see it:

```html
<input type="range"  min="0" max="100" />
```

http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

There is no slider helper class in MVC.

Add jquery ui in your view: [link](http://blog.falafel.com/three-steps-use-jquery-ui-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Example for the slider in a view:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862098/how-to-create-simple-range-slider-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: thank you for your answer, to be completly honest I am not really into jQuery UI but I will give it a try!