# Use JQuery range slider in asp.net mvc razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

Following from this question's answer: [How to create simple range slider in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862098/how-to-create-simple-range-slider-in-asp-net-mvc-3), I want to create the jquery range slider for asp.net mvc razor view based website. I am able to get the slider work in the front end but couldn't utilize or post back the required values. I tried wrapping the html in a form and do a submit, but no value is send.

Following is my code.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 1000,
            max: 50000,
            values: [12000, 15000],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
      " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    });
</script>
<form style="display:inline;" action="/mobiles/price" method="get">
                <p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

C# code, no value is received in amount.

```
public ActionResult price(string amount, int? page)
{
    Category catalog = pe.Categories.Where(cat => cat.Id == 9).Single();
    int pageIndex = page ?? 1;
    CatProView catProView = new CatProView
    {
        Name = catalog.Name,
        SubCategories = catalog.SubCategories,
        PagedProducts = catalog.Products.Where(p => p.BasePrice >= 2000 & p.BasePrice <= 10000).OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).ToPagedList(pageIndex, PageSize)
    };
        ViewBag.ToPrice = amount;
        ViewBag.FromPrice = 500;
        return View(catProView);
}
```

Actually I want to read the two range values as *from* and *to* variable from *amount* but for simplicity sake, I am trying to read the values in *amount* field first. If possible suggest me a way in which I can read the range values separately rather than *amount* string which is a combination of two range values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason your `amount` value is coming back empty is because you're using `id` (which is used by the DOM, Javascript, and CSS for identification) instead of `name` (which is used by the server-side code for identification). Just add a `name` to the input and it should be found on the server-side code:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" readonly style="color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"/>
```

For your secondary part of the question, you could use hidden fields to hold the separate range values and have those submit with the form as well.  You just have to update your slide function to update them with the visible read-only input:

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="minAmount" name="minAmount" />
<input type="hidden" id="maxAmount" name="maxAmount" />
```

**JS**

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
    $('#minAmount').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#maxAmount').val(ui.values[1]);
    $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
}
```

Just add `minAmount` and `maxAmount` to your server-side parameters and you should be able to work with the individual amounts.

Comment: tested it. Just worked the way I would have liked. Will integrate and see if I can make use at the production level now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Also thanks for clarifying things very neatly. Been coding for so long and yet forgot the `name` funda. Stupid me.

Comment: Sometimes a second set of eyes is all it takes ;) Also, be sure to mark this as an answer if it solved the problem.  It will make the question easier to find for others looking for a similar solution later