# Horizontal JQuery UI Slider

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I want to achieve the same as follows but horizontal. I tried changing the orientation to horizontal, and even leaving it out completely so it defaults to horizontal, however the colour defaults to orange. I'm using ASP.NET.

[Vertical slider, in which the filled bar change colour depending on how large the selected value gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472488/vertical-slider-in-which-the-filled-bar-change-colour-depending-on-how-large-th)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel it's a bit hard to understand what you want 100%

but I created it Horizontal for you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUXpg/190/)

[Fiddle with Orange color](http://jsfiddle.net/HUXpg/191/)

```
$(function() {

$("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "Horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 60,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        var g = parseInt(ui.value <= 50 ? 255 : 255 - ((ui.value-50)*(255/50)));
        var r = parseInt(ui.value >= 50 ? 255 : 255 - ((50-ui.value)*(255/50)));
        $(".ui-widget-header").css("background-color", "rgb("+r+","+g+",0)");  
    }
});
$("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted however have a look when I tried implementing it   https://gyazo.com/7ac4221497eaffc34f32d4f1a2852bf2